# vb6 Calling C API - MySQL Embedded

Tags: mysql, c, vb6

I am trying to connect to MySQL 5.5.48 with Embedded Server through VB6 calling conventions but doesn't know How to do it?

The MySQL document say's calling of before calling to MySql_Init

```
int mysql_server_init(int argc, char **argv, char **groups)
```

The Online example give the following Code in C:

```
static char *server_args[] = {
  "this_program",       /* this string is not used */
  "--datadir=.",
  "--key_buffer_size=32M"
};

static char *server_groups[] = {
  "embedded",
  "server",
  "this_program_SERVER",
   (char *)NULL
};

if (mysql_server_init(sizeof(server_args) / sizeof(char *),
                    server_args, server_groups)) {
//Error Message
}
```

I have tried to declare function as:

```
Public Declare Sub mysql_server_init Lib "libmySQLd" (ByVal _
    lMYSQL As Long, ByVal abc As Long, ByVal def As Long)
```

or

```
Public Declare Sub mysql_server_init Lib "libmySQLd" (ByVal _
    lMYSQL As Long, ByVal abc As String, ByVal def As String)
```

and calling

```
 call mysql_server_init(0, NULL, NULL)
```

or

```
 call mysql_server_init(0, chr(0), chr(0))
```

but the program is craching. Kindly Help me with proper calling convention between vb6 and C

Comment: It returns a long so your declarations should have tacked to the end `As Long` to indicate the return type. The constant `vbnullstring` is a null string and `vbnullchar` is `Chr(0)`. As to proper calling convention there are several.

Comment: And it's `declare function`. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx‎ for a overview of calling conventions. x64 is completely different and you can't call from VB6. COM is a more common way - Use the ADODB object with MySQL drivers installed.

Answer (score 0):

Reliably calling C DLLs from VB6 is a non-trivial process. [Check out this project](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?781595-VB6-Call-Functions-By-Pointer-(Universall-DLL-Calls)), which provides VB6 the ability to call pretty much any function from any standard DLL or COM object.

Comment: Everything is there but not how to pass pointer array I.e. char**

Comment: Are you now using the project to call the function? It's been a while since I did advanced VB6 work, so I've forgotten some of the finer points, but I found that oftentimes trial-and-error was the most effective means of figuring out how to call an unfamiliar external dll function. Try different formats of your API declaration. Try ByRef instead of ByVal. Try passing the result of VarPtr to the arguments asking for pointers. You should eventually stumble onto the right combination if someone's answer can't get you there faster.

Comment: After doing every thing I create this post used VarPTR, StrPTR, ObjPTR ByRef, ByVal